# Is there a way to include files from an e.g. package.json parent directory?

Tags: npm, include, package, npm-install, package.json

I want to be able to install local modules (below called `myLibModule1/` and `myLibModule2/`), which need to access certain dll files in the `lib/` directory.

I tried to use the `files` attribute on the `package.json` file to include `lib1.dll`, `lib2.dll` and `lib3.dll` from being installed via the `npm install <path to local module>` command.

However, it looks like `npm install <path to local module>` will just copy the whole directory into the `node_modules` folder without excluding any subfolders.

I even tried to add a package.json into the `lib/` folder and then use that folder as a dependency for my modules. This however also just copies not only all files from lib, but also all lib subfolders into my `node_modules` which leads to redundant data.

```
lib/
├── myLibModule1/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── index.js
├── myLibModule2/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── index.js
├── lib1.dll
├── lib2.dll
├── lib3.dll
├── .
├── .
├── .
└── libn.dll
```

Therefore in package.json i tried:

```
"files": [
 "../lib1.dll",
 "../lib2.dll",
 "../lib3.dll"
]
```

In the best case, i want the developer to have a module in the `node_modules` folder that looks kind of like this in the end:

```
myLibModule1/
├── package.json
├── index.js
├── lib1.dll
├── lib2.dll
└── lib3.dll
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to achieve, as well. Did you figure out a way since originally asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying in an npm **workspace** to publish some files from the parent/root package. However, a parent-folder reference like `"files": ["../someFile"]` indeed does not work.

### Workaround

Define an extra `script` in the parent package to copy the desired files to the children workspaces.

Example (assuming each child/workspace has some `dist` subdirectory, which is ignored in `.gitignore`, and which will end up with the packable files:

Parent `package.json`:

```json
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "copy_files": "for dir in lib/*; do cp *.dll \"$dir/dist/\"; done",
  }
}
```

Children `package.json`:

```json
{
  //...
  "files": {
    "dist/"
  }
}
```

Last thing to do: call the `copy_files` script at some point, for example when you are building the parent.

NOTE: the shell for loop in `copy_files` references the subdirectories with escaped double quotes to avoid errors in case, although unlikely, your workspace folders contain spaces.